# How do browsers handle jquery library?

Tags: html, browser

I have a code like this:

```
parent.html:
<head>
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#test").draggable().click(function() {
        $("#objeto").attr('data', "child2.html").draggable();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="test">text(draggable/click)</h2>
    <object id="objeto" data="child1.html"></object>
</body>
```

and

```
child2.html:
<head>
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#text").draggable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="text">child2 (draggable)
</body>
```

This works correctly, parent loads with child1 content and if you click on "text" it switches to child2, but what i want to know is:

1. am I downloading jquery.min.js  and jquery-ui.min.js 2 times? or are is the second time pulled from cache? (since i'm asking for the same file again)
2. is there a way I could use jquery without including it on the child's header? (since it is already on the parent)

Comment: They are taked from cache, unless you prevent that by your browser settings. However you can simply test that yourself. Just open your browsers development console, select the "network" tab and examine the request details.

Comment: Well, I just tested this with chrome and on the "Size" column, none of the files appear "from cache" so it means every file is being downloaded again, right?

Comment: Indeed. Question is why. Two things come into mind: 1. you disabled caching, either in your browsers settings or inside the development console, or 2. you reloaded the page, in that case also the cached pages are refreshed, since that is the expected behavior. Try navigating to the same page by the same url instead.